# c# Excel-VSTO Locking unlocking cells horrendously slow

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Just wanted to ask if anyone else experienced that in certain situations locking/unlocking cells via

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = True
```

takes extremely long. Speaking minutes here.
I can provide further details to the above question.

Comment: Since you are locking all cells anyways... I'd suggest protecting the sheet instead since it will automatically lock all cells on the sheet.  I assume that would be faster but I haven't had a case that is as slow as you are experiencing.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Hmm I thought protecting only affects cells that are locked but will give it a try.